# Sorting GridView using JQuery

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery

How can I sort gridview with JQuery using C#? Any share?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can sort any html table, there are several html-only table sorters, for example for jQuery http://tablesorter.com/docs/

however, if you have pages in your gridview, then it's not possible. there's not enough information - the other pages have to come from somewhere. to do that you can use webservice+jQuery, but that is not related to gridview at all. The much simpler way is to put gridview inside an updatepanel (but that's not using jQuery)

Comment: Because of rendered gridview is a html table the url you sent maybe good enough for me. Actually i wondered how can i sorting a table with a webmethod

Comment: you can't use webmethod with gridview - gridview is serverside only control. you can implement your own table rendering in javascript using webservie, but not sure you need to be that complicated - a simple updatepanel will do in most cases, and is very very simple to implement.